# how do find whether I am using 32 bit or 64 bit version of Git

Tags: git

I want to find out what version of Git I am running on windows- 32 bit or 64 bit. Any idea how to find that out? I am pasting whatever information I have.

```
$ git version
```

> git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1

```
vkaul@NBVK ~
$ git config -l
```

> core.symlinks=false
>      core.autocrlf=true
>      color.diff=auto
>      color.status=auto
>      color.branch=auto
>      color.interactive=true
>      pack.packsizelimit=2g
>      help.format=html
>      http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
>      sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
>      diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
>      rebase.autosquash=true
>      gui.recentrepo=C:/OCRImages_GIT
>      user.email=vivek.kaul@jumio.com
>      user.name=Vivek Kaul
>      merge.tool=kdiff3
>      core.autocrlf=true
>      core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
>      mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
>      diff.guitool=kdiff3
>      difftool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
>      http.postbuffer=2000000000
>      push.default=matching
>      pack.windowmemory=512m
>      pack.packsizelimit=2g

Answer (score 9):

This should give you the information you're looking for on any platform:

```
C:\>git --version --build-options
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
cpu: x86_64
built from commit: 2481c4cbe949856f270a3ee80c802f5dd89381aa
sizeof-long: 4
sizeof-size_t: 8
```

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate this is old, but I got frustrated trying to find the answer and then worked it out myself. It's very very simple if you use the default install location.

If your install is in `C:\Program Files\Git`, it's 64-bit. If it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git` it's 32-bit.

Comment: Unless you changed the install location to something like `c:\tools`

Answer (score 6):

Command

```
file $( which git )
```

Output

```
/usr/bin/git: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x4faadbc9c19a44ab71d1714a4e3d69e177e42a76, stripped
```

Comment: $ (which git)
/bin/git
I could not find it like that in git bash.
vkaul@NBVK ~
$ file $(which git)
sh.exe": file: command not found

Comment: git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1 kind of shows that it's windows... so not file or which by default

Answer (score 2):

Use `file`, e.g.

```
$ file `which git`
/usr/local/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the above command ? Note that those are backticks, not single quotes. If you're using Windows rather than a proper operating system then hopefully you have cygwin or similar to give you a *nix-like environment ?

Comment: I did use Cywin now, but it is not able find GIT in its path. I thought GIT bash already invokes a *nix like environment on windows

Comment: It sounds like you're not using the cygwin git, but some other git instead ?

Comment: How to do this in RHEL or CentOS?

Comment: @PaulR . Jenkins slave in AWS Linux: Linux 8e4b4932b68b 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 01:17:26 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. "file /bin/bash"
/tmp/jenkins7317351221742748373.sh: 8: /tmp/jenkins7317351221742748373.sh: file: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Comment: @ChrisF: do `which file` to see if you have the file utility. If all else fails post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it using Notepad++

1. Open git-bash.exe (or git-cmd.exe) in Notepad++
2. Go to Search>Find or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Type in `PE` and hit find next
4. Now look for the first printable character after `PE`

If it's `d` then your Git is **64 bit**

If it's `L` then your Git is **32 bit**

Answer (score 0):

On Git Bash for Windows, you can type
`where git`

> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
>   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

If it's installed in `Program Files` then you're running 64-bit.
If it's installed in `Program Files (x86)` then you're running 32-bit.